# Working with a secondary datastructure// Advice for data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to build a Graph Datastructure based on an already existing Datastructure (which I cannot modify and which is not a graph itself).
I think I have somewhat a grasp on how to build most of the structure concerning the graph itself, but right now I have to reference back to the original data structure for one little "compare" function and having a really hard time how to model that properly...

My vertices represent two different classes A and B of the original data structure, that have different member variables and no common ancestors. For an algorithm I have to check whether two vertices are compatible. 
The rule is: an A-Vertex and an B-Vertex are always incompatible, but if both vertices represent the same type I have to check some specifics for the respective type.
So the base idea is roughly like this:

```
bool isCompatible(const Vertex& other){
  // if this->data is of other type than other->data
  //    return false;
  // else return compareFunction(this->data, other->data)
       // where maybe one could overload that compare-function 
       // or make a template out of it
}
```

But I don't really know how to store the reference to data without making it really ugly.

Idea 1) Use a void pointer for data, have some variable to store the type and then cast the void pointer into respective type
-> would probably work but seems really dangerous (type-safety?) and really ugly (basically no reusability for the Graph structure if you ever wanna use it on other data). Seems a bit like the brute force approach.

Idea 2) Make an abstract data class that offers some "isCompatible(data)" function, and have wrapper-classes for A and B respectively that inherit from the abstract class and override that function. Inside the overridden function one could use dynamic_cast then and compare the objects. 
-> still doesn't seem like good design, but should also work?

Idea 3) Make templates work? It's my first time working with C++ so I'm having a few problems wrapping my head around that properly.
I think something like the following should work for comparing:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool compare(T1 object1, T2 object2){
    return false;
}
```

And then having instances for (A,A) and (B,B) that override this. For me this seems like the way to got for the comparison itself. But I don't really know how to manage the reference from Vertex to the Object without losing the Type. Any suggestions?

I'm open to any other suggestions as well of course.

edit: I'm using C++11 if that's of relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is either an `A` or a `B`, where those two types have nothing in common, then sounds like what you want is a *variant* data type. The C++ standard library doesn't have one yet, but you could use [Boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
boost::variant<A, B> data;
```

A variant gives you type safety (which `void*` doesn't) and doesn't require you to have a common ancestor between the two types (which apparently are conceptually unrelated).

With a variant like the above, you can implement your comparison using [binary visitation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.binary-visitation):

```
bool isCompatible(const Vertex& other) {
    boost::apply_visitor(is_compatible(), data, other.data);
}
```

with:

```
class is_compatible
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:

    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()( const T &, const U & ) const
    {
        return false; // cannot compare different types
    }

    bool operator()( const A& lhs, const A& rhs ) const
    {
        // whatever A-specific comparison
    }

    bool operator()( const B& lhs, const B& rhs ) const
    {
        // whatever B-specific comparison
    }    
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Hmmm if the "data"-field is private, how do you suggest asserting data to that field? passing a variant-object directly to the class (would kind of show inner workings to the outside) or having a setter for A and for B respectively or something different?

Comment: @Maike It doesn't matter that it's private. `isCompatible` is a member function, you can access it.

Comment: I'm thinking more along the line of how to initiaize my object as a whole. So when I make my Vertex should I have a constructor like `Vertex(boost::variant<A, B>)` or should I maybe make different constructors `Vertex(A)` and `Vertex(B)` to hide the variant...Seems like a stupid question, but I'm still figuring out how to use this properly I guess..

Comment: @Maike Probably the latter.